Power Supply is arced and fuses opened


Note: PFC circuit is bypassed
I have my own designed circuit and this circuit is get input of 220VAC/50Hz. Inside of circuit bridge rectifier and filters are exist with this circuit we get 320VDC. So this DC goes the high frequency inverter. For controller circuitry low voltage I need 12V and 3.3V I planned to give this power with power supply from outside.
At first I test both control circuit, inverter and AC/DC seperetly no problem observed. After I connect both of them and close the fuse of input 220VAC of circuit the arcing observed at power supply(12V and 3.3V feed the control circuit), fuses are opened and 12V/3.3V feeded ICs and MCU are not working anymore other parts are working I guess I test some of them no problem observed. Can problem because of AC ground?
I only connect Phase and Netural to input AC, I didn't connect ground to PCB. But oscilloscope and power supply has a ground connection can be problem solved with banding the ground connection?

You need to draw a schematic to show how all this is connected.

Both 12V and 3.3V is feeding via power supply from outside as I said and that power supply energized from same grid 220AC.

@MSB yeah but it does not describe if your 12V supply output is floating or earthed. The scope definitely is earthed, assuming it plugs into mains, and is not running on batteries.

Your node called "PGND" is technically live, with each negative AC sine cycle, it goes from 0V to -325V and back to 0V.
You cannot connect any Protective Earth referenced devices like power supplies or oscilloscopes to PGND or any other terminal.
And no, the answer is not to float the scope by preventing scope/supply PE connection to the mains socket PE terminal, or using an isolation transformer to the scope/supplies, as then by connecting them to your circuit they will become live too, and all other circuits they connect to.
So since you asked if the PE connection can be disconnected, the answer is technically yes/maybe, but that is extremely dangerous and you already made short circuits between live and PE, you likely should not do things in a way that are extemely dangerous even if technically you could.
Consider using an isolation transformer, but to your mains circuit.
Also try to have a larger view of what items are and what are not PE referenced, i.e. if you define PE (and/or Neutral) as 0V, what nodes have what voltages in reference to PE.

Sir I agree its really dangerous to disconnect PE. At the start I am designing to flyback circuit for getting 12V and 3.3V it can solve the PE problem i guess. But that circuit currently have some issues so Its not the case right now. But I don't understand isolation transformer you say. At the Input should I add a transformer that for example 220V to 24V step down with that I rectify and regulate the 12V/3.3V? Am I getting right?

And other things makes me confused is the isolation transformer would be in my upper commend example, pretty big because of 50Hz. So can I do this with my flyback I guess? 320VDC to 12V/3.3V flyback.

@MSB It depends on what power you need. Desktop isolation transformers are about the size of couple of bricks. You can generate an isolated 12V/3.3V but still your 320VDC unisolated circuits cannot be probed with a scope unless you isolate the 320VDC supply.

I understand but if I isolate the 12V and 3.3V from main circuit. Now they have seperate grounds aren't this cause switching problem since 12V and 3.3V is required at IR2110.
